# Custom string include angular span

Tags: angularjs, string, customization

I am having span in my MVC view and pass data to span. I want to show like

```
  Test : 5 (3)
```

I tried like following :

```
 $scope.getDetails = function (id) {
            localApi.getAlldetails(id)
                .then(function (data) {
                    $scope.importtypes = data;  
                }).catch(function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                }).finally(function () {

                });
        }
 <tr ng-repeat="importtype in importtypes">
<td>    <span ng-if="importtype.Total != 0">Test :  {{importtype.Total}}  ({{importtype.MatchTotal}}) </span> 
</td></tr>
```

It shows as :  `Test : 5`
Can anyone help me to do this ..
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: What issue you are facing?

Comment: Are you sure myVal.MatchTotal is well typed ? seems like it is undefined.

Comment: `Test : 5 ()` here `()` also not coming?

Comment: Test : 5 () is coming

Comment: Then check your `myVal.MatchTotal` you don't have value in this as mentioned by @ManuelObregozo

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code.  What does the myVal pbject look like?  I'm guess that's where your issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - avoid `{{}}` in dom elements because of performance. You can use ng-bind-template directive.

```
<span ng-if="myVal.Total != 0" ng-bind-template="Test :  {{myVal.Total}}  ({{myVal.MatchTotal}})"> </span>
```

Second thing is that `myVal.MatchTotal` is null in context of specific digest that's why you don't have value there. You are using ng-if statement here - do you fill `myVal.MatchTotal` value after content is loaded? If so then `myVal.MatchTotal` won't be updated because ng-if creates subscope and value is included on dom only on first digest iteration - but angular do not observe `myVal.MatchTotal` for changes. If both values `{{myVal.Total}}  ({{myVal.MatchTotal}})` are going to change after loading content then apply `$parent` to it.

```
<span ng-if="myVal.Total != 0" ng-bind-template="Test :  {{$parent.myVal.Total}}  ({{$parent.myVal.MatchTotal}})"> </span>
```

Comment: Provide more code then - especially code from controller and whole html

Comment: need to add string 'Test' before actual data. So ng-bind-template can't be used?

Comment: Can be used because it is ng bind template :), you are fetching code async, you need to add $parent as it is described in the example that I've provided

Comment: ng-bind-template="Test: {{myVal.Total}} ({{myVal.unMatchTotal}})" I tried with this and the result is Test: 5(). When tried with $parent, no value is displayed

Comment: myval.unmatchtotal or myval.matchtotal? Provide console.log(myval) plz

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<span ng-if="myVal.Total != 0">Test :  {{myVal.Total + "(" + myVal.MatchTotal + ")" }} </span>
```

Comment: Where is your `MatchTotal `?

Answer (score 0):

I think your myVal.MatchTotal is undefined.

Check it ,It is working.

```
   <html lang="en-US">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
      <body>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('app',[]).controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
          $scope.myVal = {
           Total: 5,
           MatchTotal: 3
         }
       })
     </script>
     <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="testCtrl">
      <span ng-if="myVal.Total != 0">Test :  {{myVal.Total}} ({{myVal.MatchTotal}})</span> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```